# Refactoring CNContactPicker UI Code using the delegate pattern in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-protocols

I have implemented the `CNContactPickerViewController` ContactsUI provided by iOS in iOS10 succesfully in a view controller so I can have a user select multiple contacts to invite to an event. I am trying to reduce the size of this single view controller by implementing the delegate pattern, and am stuck on a black screen. I have looked at a few resources, and think I am calling the delegate and defining the protocol accordingly. I have a view controller, `CreateEventViewController` and it implements my self defined `ContactsToInviteDelegate`. This protocol is as follows:

```
protocol ContactsToInviteDelegate : class {
     //array of array of KV-pairs where inner array is {"email":"email@gmail.com", "phone": "+18965883371"}
    //array of JSON objects to upload
    func contactsToInvite(_ contactsStructure: [[String:String]])
}
```

My ContactPickerViewController self defined class is as follows:

```
class ContactPickerViewController: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {
    //class variables
    let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()
    weak var delegate: ContactsToInviteDelegate?
    var contactsToSendInvitesTo = [[String:String]]()

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
        contacts.forEach { contact in
            let phoneNum = contact.phoneNumbers.first
            var stringPhoneNumber = String()
            do{
                let phoneNumber = try self.phoneNumberKit.parse((phoneNum?.value.stringValue)!, withRegion: "US", ignoreType:true)
            stringPhoneNumber = "+1\(phoneNumber.adjustedNationalNumber())"
            print(stringPhoneNumber)
            }
            catch {
                print("phone number parsing error")
            }

            let contactDisplayName = contact.givenName
            print("displayName: \(contactDisplayName)" )

            let contactEmail = contact.emailAddresses.first?.value ?? ""
            print("email: \(contactEmail)")

            self.contactsToSendInvitesTo.append(["email":contactEmail as String, "phone":stringPhoneNumber])
        }
        delegate?.contactsToUpload(self.contactsToSendInvitesTo)
    }

    func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
        print("cancel contact picker")
    }

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController,didSelectContactProperties contactProperties: [CNContactProperty]) {

    }

}
```

And in the `CreateEventViewController` I am calling the delegate when i click the invite users button and implementing the method of the protocol to just attempt to print the final structure displaying contacts emails and phone numbers to send invitations to:

```
func selectContactsPicker() {
        let cnPicker = ContactPickerViewController()
        cnPicker.delegate = ContactPickerViewController() as? ContactsToInviteDelegate
        self.present(cnPicker, animated:true, completion:nil)

}

func contactsToInvite(_ contactsStructure: [[String : String]]) {
    print(contactsStructure)
}
```

This code without refactoring to try to use the delegate pattern worked before. I had all these functions within one single view controller, but with all the logic required this file itself is extending beyond 400+ lines. My problem now is that after attempting to refactor using the delegate pattern, when i click the button to trigger `selectContactsPicker` all I see is a black screen. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I have a feeling it is this function itself. I am not quite sure what the body of this function should be in order to delegate the responsibility to the correct controller, or how to display it properly. Examples I saw used storyboards and segues, such as [this](https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef). I looked at other examples for using delegates but I think my problem is a bit too specific and I don't know how to ask in a more general sense. If I did, I would probably not have this problem to begin with, as then I would probably properly understand how to implement the delegate pattern.

Comment: You are instantiating ContactPickerViewController but it has no content, so you will get a black screen. You need to load some content programmatically or from a storyboard or XIB.  Before you refactored the code how did you define the view content?

Comment: @Dale before i simply `let cnPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()` which is the ContactsUI directly. Now I am trying to delegate the code using the data from ContactsUI, but unsure how or where to instantiate the ContactsUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate does not have to be a view controller. This is a convenient pattern when a view controller manages elements requiring delegates - rather than instantiate separate objects just let the view controller implement the protocol.

There are a number of ways to manage unruly view controllers which grow too large.

One simple way is to use extensions. To add a delegate protocol to an existing view controller:

```
extension SomeViewController : CNContactPickerDelegate {

   ... implement contact picker delegate methods

}
```

This can nicely compartmentalise your source code making it easier to read.

If you want to use a separate class instance as the delegate, that can be done quite easily too.

Declare your delegate class, either in the same source file or another:

```
class MyPickerDelegate : NSObject, CNContactPickerDelegate {

   ... implement contact picker delegate methods

}
```

note the class must inherit from NSObject, but does not need to be a UIViewController.

In the code where you fire up the contact picker:

```
picker = CNContactPickerViewController()
self.pickerDelegate = MyPickerDelegate()
picker.delegate = self.pickerDelegate
self.present(picker, animated: true)
```

Note picker view controller only keeps a weak reference to the delegate, so you must make sure to keep a strong reference to the object somewhere. Here I am using a property pickerDelegate